# How to remove a specific Size Class from a storyboard?

Tags: xcode, swift, size-classes

I'm worjìking on a testing project. All the project is in wAny hAny size class but I accidentally worked for some minutes in wRegular hCompact, now in wAny hAny there are elements that aren't present in wAny hAny which I refer to in the code, so the I get errors when running the project in simulator. How can I get rid of wRegular hCompact size class?

EDIT
Two screenshot of the current situation. There are not constrains but some elements are moved when switching from a size class to another.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see which constraints are associated with a view by selecting it and then selecting the Size Inspector button in the Utilities pane.

[image]

Double click on the constraint you want to inspect which will show you all the size classes a constraint is installed for. Click on the little X next to the size class that you wish to remove it from. In this case wC hR.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Casey Fleser, I removed all the constrains so when I get info for any control I get this message: "The selected views have no constraints. At build time, explicit left, top, width, and height constraints will be generated for the view.". Unfortunately when I switch from a Size Class to another (e.g. from wAny hAny to wRegular hCompact), Interface Builder continues to move elements (in particular a textField) to another position. Do you think there is a way to completly remove all Size Classes to start from scratch?

Comment: You may not have added any constraints for Any / Any since you did all this in Regular / Compact? Or you could nuke all the constraints and start from scratch if you're desperate. With the outline view visible on the left, open all the disclosure triangles, select all the constraints you can find and hit Delete.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to see whether there are constrains hidden in some place. The project is for learning purposes so there is no problem to reset the constrains. PS I added two screenshots to try to clarify the problem.

Comment: I got rid of all the specific settings of each size class, by clearing the box Use Size Classes in the storyboard's file inspector and then re-selecting it. The project has reset to the initial settings. Thank you for your precious help Casey Fleser.